# Gunicorn fails because ModuleNotFoundError: No module named celery

Tags: python, django, celery, gunicorn

I have moved my django app from my local environment to a server.  I installed all the dependencies that my local environment has.  However, gunicorn is failing because it says:

```
from celery import Celery
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named celery
```

This file is my celery.py file.

I have already installed Celery via pip (pip install celery).  Run celery, celery-beat, and flower run in terminals successfully.  Also, from the Python shell, I get the following:

```py
>>> from celery import Celery
>>> Celery
<class 'celery.app.base.Celery'>
```

So it seems like Celery is installed and even working, but for some reason my app is failing to due celery not being recognized.  Any help identifying the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that the environment in which you're seeing this problem has more than one Python installation and you're not using the one you think you are. Try adding *import sys; print(sys.version_info)*. That *may* reveal something

Comment: That was it.  I was working in a conda environment rather than the base environment that gunicorn was looking at.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I highly encourage you to use a virtual environment. This way you'll never have to worry about which Python environment is being used. You create a virtual environment with the Python interpreter that you want, and install all necessary packages there. It also keeps you from polluting your Python environment with tons of packages that might not work with each other. Its as simple as running the following in your terminal:

`python3.10 -m venv venv && source venv/bin/activate`

[Docs here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)